# What is the Meaning of "DEFAULT" in Mysql Datetime?

Tags: mysql

In this following mysql command i am seeing the Keyword **DEFAULT**

```
CREATE Table User
(
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    created_at datetime DEFAULT NULL
)
```

**My Question Is :**

1. Why is there a default keyword if i am allowing datetime to be null
2. Is it about the Datetime syntax, so that it should be in default format.

please explain it to me. I also found the documentation page for DEFAULT in mysql. but i am not understanding it.

*[N.B.: Pardon Me, If this a beginner question, or already asked. But I did not find exactly what i was looking for.]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Why is there a default keyword if i am allowing datetime to be null

You mistake the `NULL` after `DEFAULT` with the `NULL` that allows a column to contain `NULL` values. Read below about the difference.

> 2. Is it about the Datetime syntax, so that it should be in default format.

The `DEFAULT` keyword in a [`CREATE TABLE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) doesn't tell anything about any format. It specifies the default value to be used for the column when an [`INSERT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) doesn't provide a value for it.

The complete definition of a table column in the `CREATE TABLE` statement contain the following pieces, in this order:

- field name;
- field type;
- `NULL` or `NOT NULL` - are `NULL` values allowed to be stored in the field? If neither is specified, `NULL` is assumed;
- `DEFAULT` *default value* - the value to be used for the field when an `INSERT` statement doesn't provide a value for it; `NULL` can be used as default value if the column is nullable; if it's not specified, MySQL uses some rules to compute the default value based on the field type;
- `AUTO_INCREMENT` - when a value is not provided for the column, MySQL uses the biggest value existing in the column plus one; can be used only with integer and float columns;
- one of `UNIQUE`, `UNIQUE KEY`, `KEY`, `PRIMARY KEY` - the first two are equivalent and they specify that the column is an unique index of the table (it cannot contain the same value for two or more rows); the last two specify the column is the identifier of the row (it is an `UNIQUE INDEX` and it cannot contain `NULL` values); these attributes can be specified here for compatibility with other database systems; on MySQL one usually specifies the table indexes after the columns using a different syntax;
- `COMMENT` *string* - a comment for the column; it is not used by MySQL but it can be useful for the developers (to specify what represents the column);
- other, less used, options.

Only the first two pieces from the list above (the name and the type) are required; all the others are optional. If present, they must be provided in the order of the list.

Your statement:

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
)
```

The column `id` specifies `NOT NULL`, skips `DEFAULT` and specifies `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Without `AUTO_INCREMENT`, MySQL uses `0` as the default value (this is the default value for integer types). Because of `AUTO_INCREMENT`, when a value is not provided in the `INSERT` statement, MySQL finds the largest value already stored in the column, increases it with `1` and uses this computed value for the column.

The column `created_at` doesn't specify if it allows `NULL` values (it allows them, this is the default) and specifies that the default value for the column is `NULL`.

#### Examples

Let's see how it works:

```
INSERT INTO User(id, created_at) VALUES (5, '2016-06-01 11:22:33')
```

inserts a new row having the values provided in the `INSERT` statement; no surprise here.

```
INSERT INTO User(created_at) VALUES ('2016-06-02 12:34:56')
```

inserts a new row with `id = 6`, `created_at = '2016-06-02 12:34:56'`. Because a value was not provided for column `id`, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option generated `6` for it (the successor of the larger value already in the column).

The same happens when `NULL` is provided for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column:

```
INSERT INTO User(id, created_at) VALUES (NULL, '2016-06-03')
```

inserts `id = 7`, `created_at = '2016-06-03 00:00:00'`. Please also note that, because the time components were not specified in the value provided for `created_at`, MySQL defaulted them to `00:00:00`.

A new statement:

```
INSERT INTO User(id) VALUES (10)
```

creates a row having `id = 10`, `created_at = NULL`.

The statement

```
INSERT INTO User() VALUES()
```

looks strange but it's perfectly legal and inserts a row that uses the default values for all its columns. In this case, the new row have the values `id = 11`, `created_at = NULL`.

Finally, the statement

```
INSERT INTO User(id) VALUES(5)
```

fails because there already exists a row having `id = 5` in the table (it was inserted by the first statement at the start of the examples.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Why is there a default keyword if i am allowing datetime to be null**

> If a column definition includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL determines the default value as described in [Section 12.7, “Data Type Default Values”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html).

MySQL will add default value to column definition by it's own rules if you don't set it manually. So, `DEFAULT` is always presented, except special datatypes

> DEFAULT does not apply to the BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY, and JSON types

**2. Is it about the Datetime syntax, so that it should be in default format.**

No. If you allow null, then column can take any valid datetime value OR null. Null is valid too. And [from manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause.

As result, if you create table with column `created_at datetime` it will be converted according these rules to `created_at datetime DEFAULT NULL`.

***Update***

Some examples. Next `CREATE TABLE` statements are equivalent:

```sql
CREATE Table User
(
    created_at datetime NULL
);

CREATE Table User
(
    created_at datetime DEFAULT NULL
);
```

You said, that you "allow null" for this column. Probably, you was using first query with `created_at datetime NULL` syntax. But MySQL really translates it into second query, because of rules above.

Comment: can you give me an example? plz

Answer (score 2):

The `DEFAULT` constraint is used to insert a default value into a column.

The `default` value will be added to all new records, if no other value is specified.

The [DEFAULT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.

For More Information See This Question. 
[MySQL columns with default null - stylistic choice, or is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253415/mysql-columns-with-default-null-stylistic-choice-or-is-it)

Comment: then why there NULL is specified here?

Comment: To explicitly define `null` as the default value. Without a default value, failure to manually specify that column's value in new rows will result in a warning or error.

Answer (score 1):

Think of [`NULL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) as *unknown*. This has interesting implications, like:

```
mysql> select null = true;
+-------------+
| null = true |
+-------------+
|        NULL |
+-------------+
```

and

```
mysql> select null != true;
+--------------+
| null != true |
+--------------+
|         NULL |
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MySQL Data Type Default Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html)

> If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause.

For MySQL those definitions are all same and identical

```
column type
column type NULL
column type DEFAULT NULL
column type NULL DEFAULT NULL
```