# mysql primary key null value

Tags: mysql, database

I read that Primary key should be Unique and not null. Now when I create a table `checking` with `depid` as primary key, the table description says this according to me : the `Null` column value `NO` indicates that `depid` can't be `Null` but at the same time the `Default` column value `Null` says that default is `Null`

```
mysql> desc checking;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| depid | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| deppp | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into checking values(1,2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> insert into checking(deppp) values(1);
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'depid' doesn't have a default value
```

If that is the case why is the last query producing an error?

**Edit** The error got resolved once primary key column is labelled as `Auto Increment`. But that still doesn't explain why the `Default` column shows `Null` for a primary key column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL columns with default null - stylistic choice, or is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253415/mysql-columns-with-default-null-stylistic-choice-or-is-it)

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot adding the "auto increment" to your primary key, so there is no value added. Create your table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE checking (
    depid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    deppp int(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (depid)
);
```

Comment: but why does the `default` column value shows `Null` for a primary key when reading the description of the table